# Sorting data in Java based on given hierarchy and given level

Tags: java, sorting

I am trying to find out the approach for sorting a provided dataset in a Hashmap.
The data need to sorted by for all the weeks in first column, for the product and within a channel for all the stores. 
The Stores are mapped to a particular channel and hence when sorting the data only stores should be ranked within a channel not across all the channels.
I can get this relationship in another hashmap (channel,store mapping)
The output is need to be list product,store ,rank

I need some starting pointers to work on the problem and any example would be helpful.

Example data set:

```
    w20150608,product1,str2,0.45003933910307
    w20150615,product1,str2,0.46734854445319
    w20150622,product1,str2,0.48790322580645
    w20150629,product1,str2,0.41114558437124
    w20150706,product1,str3,0.44112494989831
    w20150713,product1,str3,0.46425188901919
    w20150720,product1,str3,0.46339533571842
    w20150727,product1,str1,0.4736739753277
    w20150817,product1,str1,0.44352216102806
    w20150824,product1,str1,0.43260774543229
    w20150629,product1,str1,0.082229116874248
    w20150706,product1,str1,0.088224989979662
    w20150713,product1,str1,0.092850377803839
    w20150720,product1,str4,0.092679067143684
    w20150727,product1,str4,0.09473479506554
    w20150803,product1,str4,0.1178756884343
    w20150810,product1,str1,0.10616749715884
    w20150817,product1,str1,0.088704432205613
    w20150824,product1,str1,0.086521549086459
    w20150831,product1,str1,0.087974955411327
```

Answer (score 2):

I would generate an Object out of the data. So an  Object has the properties week, product, store and value. Now you put them in a List (ArrayList for Example).

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<DataObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(DataObject o1, DataObject o2) {
        if(o1.getWeek() <> o2.getWeek())
            return o1.getWeek().compareTo(o2.getWeek());
        if(o1.getProduct() <>  o2.getProduct())
            return o1.getProduct().compareTo(o2.getProduct());
         else
            return o1.getStore().compareTo(o2.getStore())
    }
}
```

Then sort the List with the Comparator.

A Hashmap can't be sorted directly.